# Как в Kotlin отключить сеттер по умолчанию

Tags: kotlin, setter

Можно ли в kotlin отключить сеттер по умолчанию?

Например есть класс Duck

```
class Duck {
    var name : String
    var type : String
}
```

из него вызываются дефолтные геттеры и сеттеры, хорошо

Модифицируем

```
class Duck {
    var name : String
    fun name(name : String) = apply { this.name = name }

    var type : String
    fun type(type : String) = apply { this.type = type }
}
```

теперь у нас есть класс с билдером, но у него остались дефолтные геттеры и сеттеры. Геттеры нужны, а сеттеры - нет, всё таки ооп, всё таки класс надо только билдером создавать. В java я бы просто выделил сеттеры и нажал бы backspace или delete в зависимости от настроения. А как избавиться от ненужных сеттеров в kotlin?

И вдогонку - вот я сделал билдер, но могу вызывать его только как метод

```
object.{builderMethod}(value)
```

Есть ли возможность переопределить стандартный сеттер таким образом, чтобы он стал методом билдера и вызывался как типичный сеттер в котлине?

```
object.value = newValue
```

Answer (score 6):

А документацию почитать? :)
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Сеттер можно сделать приватным

```
class Duck {
  var name : String
    private set
  var type : String
    private set
}
```

По поводу изменения поведения проперти стоит почитать о Delegated Properties
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html